# How to match single encoded and double encoded meta characters in django url dispatcher

Tags: python, regex, django, encoding

I need to match encoded meta characters in django urls to avoid Open Redirect Vulnerability.
e.g.

```
https://abc.mysite.net/http:%5C%5Cwww.google.com
```

can be matched as:

```
url(r'.\\\\.', RedirectView.as_view(url='/login/', permanent=False),),
```

How to match double encoded characters e.g.

```
https://abc.mysite.net/http:%255C%255Cwww.google.com
```

Or is there a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: do you need to match un-encoded, single-encoded _and_ double-encoded, or just double-encoded?

Comment: also I don't think the example regex `r'.\\\\.'` will really match the single-encoded version of the url as given above

Comment: @Anentropic I need to match un-encoded, single-encoded and double-encoded. The url pattern does match the single encoded version.

Comment: true... I didn't realise your encoded url decodes to `http:\\www.google.com` i.e. backslashes instead of forward slashes